# Delete rows from Pandas dataframe if rows exist in another dataframe BUT KEEP COLUMNS FROM BOTH DATAFRAMES (NOT DUPLICATE)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different Pandas data-frames that have one column in common. Example:

dataframe 1

```
ID  col1 col2  ...
1    -    -
2    -    -
3    -    - 
4    -    -
```

dataframe 2

```
ID  col3  col4  ...
3    -     -
4    -     -
7    -     -
```

What I want to achieve is a dataframe with columns from both dataframes but without the ID's found in dataframe2. i.e:

desired result:

```
ID  col1 col2  col3  col4
1    -    -     -     -
2    -    -     -     -
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what is in col3 and col4 in output DataFrame? Because not exist data for id 1, 2.

Comment: It's impossible to understand what you want. Give a decent example!